# Rotate categoryField on AmCharts v3

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmCharts v3 to add charts to my PHP page. The category axis labels in my charts are legible when the charts don't have a lot of data, but the labels overlap when there is a large amount of data. Is there a way to rotate the labels so that they don't overlap?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`labelRotation`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryAxis/#labelRotation_property) in your `categoryAxis` to rotate the labels. To rotate them vertically:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  categoryAxis: {
    labelRotation: 90,
    // ...
  }
});
```

There's also [`autoRotateCount`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryAxis/#autoRotateCount_property) and [`autoRotateAngle`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryAxis/#autoRotateAngle_property), which can be used to automatically rotate the labels if there's more than a specified number of axis labels instead of always rotating them using `labelRotation`.